# JQuery function not getting fired

Tags: jquery

Am retrieving state list based on the country list and retrieving cities based on the chosen state. Am using JQuery and Ajax for that. first jquery function is getting fired but the second jquery function is not getting fired even though I have specified my field id correctly

```
    $(document)
    .ready(
            function() {


                $('#countryId').on('change',function(){

                    jQuery
                    .ajax({


                     error : function() {

                            $("#stateSelectBox")
                                    .html(
                                            "<span class='error'>Failed to load state!</span>");

                        },
                        success : function(results) {

                            $("#stateSelectBox")
                                    .html(results);

                        } 
                    });

                    });



                $('#stateId').on('change',function(){



                    jQuery
                    .ajax({


                        error : function() {

                                $("#city")
                                        .html(
                                                "<span class='error'>Failed to load state!</span>");

                            },
                            success : function(results) {

                                $("#city")
                                        .html(results);

                            } 

                    });

                    });

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first success callback you are inserting the html inside the DOM. so the second check box will not be available in the DOM When the document is ready. so place the second selector inside the success callback so that when jquery looks for that particular element in the DOM it will find it and attach your event. hope it helps.

```
$(document)
.ready(
        function() {


            $('#countryId').on('change',function(){
                alert('mogana');
                var country_id="";
                country_id = $(this).val();

                jQuery
                .ajax({
                    data : "country="
                            + country_id,

                    url : "stateMapAction.action",
                    type : "POST",

                 error : function() {

                        $("#stateSelectBox")
                                .html(
                                        "<span class='error'>Failed to load state!</span>");

                    },
                    success : function(results) {

                        $("#stateSelectBox")
                                .html(results);

             $('#stateId').on('change',function(){

                alert('swe');
                var state_id="";
                state_id=$(this).val();

                jQuery
                .ajax({

                    data : "state="
                            + state_id,

                    url: "cityMapAction.action",
                    type: "POST",


                    error : function() {

                            $("#citySelectBox")
                                    .html(
                                            "<span class='error'>Failed to load state!</span>");

                        },
                        success : function(results) {

                            $("#citySelectBox")
                                    .html(results);

                        } 

                });

                });


                    } 
                });

                });




            });
```